# How to properly lookup for several fields in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say i have 2 collections

```
// Post collection:
{
    "_id": "61f7a933b209737de4cc2657",
    "author": "61d30188cf93e83e08d14112",
    "title": "Some title",
    "createts": 1643620659355
}
```

```
// User collection:

{
    "_id": "61d30188cf93e83e08d14112",
    "nickname": "Bob",
    "link": "bobspage"
}
```

And i need to get this result

```
{
    "_id": "61f7a933b209737de4cc2657",
    "author": {
        "_id": "61d30188cf93e83e08d14112",
        "nickname": "Bob",
        "link": "bobspage"
    },
    "title": "Some title",
    "createts": 1643620659355
}
```

How can i make a request with **aggregation**, which will display this output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `$lookup` in an aggregation query:

- First `$lookup`, which generate a field called `author` which is an array with all values joined.
- To get `author` as an object get the first result for the array using `$arrayElemAt`.

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "author": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$author",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3SgJFPd4fs-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @J.F. !
I have another one:
What if i need only "nickname" field from User collection ?

Comment: You can use a `$project` stage to output the values you want. Like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TLaoW4l8Kcg) or like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rguG4c-NjzY) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and for the examples.